# removing "_" from a very large csv file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have a large csv file (120GB) that looks like this:

```
"JE",865438083645,2012-12-05T23:07:36.000Z,24,"NQ",142,"658_55525",475035504705
"JE",875619112765,2012-12-05T23:58:04.000Z,4,"PG",144,"219_9221",835399289335
"JE",125495251245,2012-12-05T18:16:06.000Z,206,"PLJE",153,"763_60771",445355650435
```

I would like to remove the underscore and the quotation marks from the values in the seventh column (e.g., `"658_55525"` becomes `65855525`). The import tool for the database I am using doesn't allow casting or manipulating the file on import.

What would be an efficient way to do it from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about efficient, but sed with a regular expression.  Make a backup of the file in case you make a typo, but perhaps something like this:

```
sed -i  's/"\([0-9]\+\)_\([0-9]\+\)"/\1\2/' bigcsvfile.csv
```

Edit: removed the g, as kos pointed out, no g is needed.

Comment: The `g` switch is not useful here, since you're matching a single instance. Also you can avoid escaping parenthesis by using the `-r` option

Answer (score 2):

**Perl is simply the fastest when editing large files.**

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/"([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)"/$1$2/' your_file.csv
```

Your backup file is in

```
your_file.csv.bak
```

**Without a backup:**

```
perl -pi -e 's/"([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)"/$1$2/' your_file.csv
```

Comment: You don't need the `g` switch here since you're matching a single instance

Comment: @kos Oh yes, of course. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your file is big, I'd suggest to use `gawk` > `4.10.0` instead of `awk`, which supports in-place editing.

Using `gawk` > `4.10.0`:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","}; {gsub(/["_]/,"",$7); print}' inputfile
```

- `-i inplace`: tells `gawk` to edit the file in-place

`awk` script breakdown:

- `BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","}`: sets the field separator and the output field separator to `,`
- `gsub(/["_]/,"",$7)`: replaces the `"` and `_` characters contained in the 7th field of the record with an empty string
- `print`: prints the record

Comment: no need for two functions `$ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{gsub(/["_]/, "", $7)}1' file
"JE",865438083645,2012-12-05T23:07:36.000Z,24,"NQ",142,65855525,475035504705
"JE",875619112765,2012-12-05T23:58:04.000Z,4,"PG",144,2199221,835399289335
"JE",125495251245,2012-12-05T18:16:06.000Z,206,"PLJE",153,76360771,445355650435
`